# Why is area lighting creating a grainy render?

Tags: rendering

I started to use Blender last week, so I'm kinda new here. I was wondering if someone could check the lighting in my house model? I believe that is what is causing all of my grainy and low quality renders. I have tried many solutions such as increasing the resolution to 100%, enabling *Multiple Importance Sampling*, using regular *Path Tracing* with square samples instead of *Branched Path Tracing*, and messing around with the *Render Tab* settings. I'm still trying to figure out why my animation is taking more than 8 hours to render a simple three second video and why it is so blurry. My windows laptop has an NVIDIA GT 520M, 8GB of ram, and a 64-bit operating system. This is for an important school project and it weight 98% of my grade. I hope someone can help:)

My Blender file:

[image]

[image]

*The final render is too grainy and poor quality.*

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

In your scene, one of the first things I noticed was that it was inside an enclosed space. Bluriness in enclosed spaces can often be caused by unpowerful lighting.

### Solution

I selected the area lamp near the top of the cabin and turned up the *Emission Strength* to 1000 from 300. I also turned the *Max Bounces:* to 1024.

#### I also optimized the .blend file.

I made some adjustments in the *Render tab* of the *Properties panel*, namely that I set the *Max:* and *Min:* Light Path Bounces to 0 (for faster rendering). I also turned the *Filter Glossy:* value to 0.7. Additionally, I changed the resolution to just 1920x1080 (1080p; you had it set to 4k which really won't make any difference except causing the rendering to take 4 times as long). Furthermore, I turned the *Sampling > Settings: > Clamp Indirect:* value to 3.00. I turned the AA render samples to 100. Lastly, I optimized the Tile Size for CPU rendering (*Properties panel > Render Tab > Performance Drop Down Menu > Tiles:*). If you want it to be optimized for GPU rendering, change each (x/y) from *16* to *256*.

On my 8-year-old mac with CPU and not all the image textures, one frame (probably) took a bit under an hour (I didn't wait for it to finish). On my Nvidia 970 4GB STRIX, one frame took just 54 seconds and looked like this:

[image]

### Final Notes

Here is the fixed up .blend file:

[image]

*I don't generally offer this (haven't before), but if you can get me a .blend file with all the images included, I will render it for you. 90 frames x 1 min each = about 90 min. --A fellow Blender-using student.*